# How to use a separate .cpp file for my event function definitions in windows forms?

Tags: c++, winforms, function, visual-c++, c++-cli

I'm having trouble defining my C++ event functions in windows forms.

I want to define my event functions (example: button click) in a separate .cpp file instead of doing all the function definitions in the windows forms .h file that's already full of generated code for the windows forms GUI.

I tried doing this, 
Declaration inside the Form1.h class:

```
private: System::Void ganttBar1_Paint
(System::Object^  sender, System::Windows::Forms::PaintEventArgs^  e);
```

And this is the definition inside Form1.cpp class:

```
#include "Form1.h"

System::Void Form1::ganttBar1_Paint(System::Object^  sender, System::Windows::Forms::PaintEventArgs^  e)
{
    // Definition
}
```

When I do this i get compiler errors in the .cpp file saying that it's not a class or namespace name.

**What can i do to get the definitions and declarations of the event functions in seprate files?**

Am I just being stupid and missing something here or do i have to do these things in another way than the C++ standard?

Comment: not sure this has anything necessarily to do with C++ standard, is this not some C++/cli design rationale?

Comment: @EdChum : It's not a design _rationale_ so much as a poor WinForms code generator that doesn't know how to separate declarations from definitions.

Comment: @ildjarn apologies just re-read the last line and understand what the OP is saying, a post of the generated code would help though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your class definition is most likely inside of some namespace (I'll use `Project1` as a placeholder):

```
#pragma once

namespace Project1
{
    ref class Form1 : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
    {
        // ...
    };
}
```

Consequently, your definition needs to be as well:

```
#include "Form1.h"

namespace Project1
{
    void Form1::ganttBar1_Paint(System::Object^ sender, System::Windows::Forms::PaintEventArgs^ e)
    {
        // definition
    }
}
```

or

```
#include "Form1.h"

void Project1::Form1::ganttBar1_Paint(System::Object^ sender, System::Windows::Forms::PaintEventArgs^ e)
{
    // definition
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I forgot about the namespace, it now works like a charm!