# Visual c++ CLR form project. use separate c++ file for functions

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have a windows forms project. Rather than having all of my functions and callbacks in the forms header file along with all of the automatically generated code, I would like to place them in a separate c++ file.

I have found this post which answers the question, however I can not get it to work. I must be missing something: [How to use a separate .cpp file for my event function definitions in windows forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10305922/how-to-use-a-separate-cpp-file-for-my-event-function-definitions-in-windows-for)

In my separate c++ file I have tried the following:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "DeltaForm.h"

namespace DeltaControl
{
    // Search for all serial ports and add them to the port combobox
    void searchPorts(void)
    {
        array<Object^>^ portsArray = SerialPort::GetPortNames();
        this->cbPort->Items->AddRange( portsArray );
    }

}
```

Which gives the output:

```
    1>test.cpp(10): error C2355: 'this' : can only be referenced inside non-static member functions
    1>test.cpp(10): error C2227: left of '->cbPort' must point to class/struct/union/generic type
    1>test.cpp(10): error C2227: left of '->Items' must point to class/struct/union/generic type
    1>test.cpp(10): error C2227: left of '->AddRange' must point to class/struct/union/generic type
```

And this:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "DeltaForm.h"

namespace DeltaControl
{
    // Search for all serial ports and add them to the port combobox
    void DeltaForm::searchPorts(void)
    {
        array<Object^>^ portsArray = SerialPort::GetPortNames();
        this->cbPort->Items->AddRange( portsArray );
    }

}
```

Output:

```
1>test.cpp(7): error C2039: 'searchPorts' : is not a member of 'DeltaControl::DeltaForm'
1>          f:\documents\cloud\projects\deltarobot\deltarobotcontrol_vcpp\deltacontrol\deltacontrol\DeltaForm.h(16) : see declaration of 'DeltaControl::DeltaForm'
1>test.cpp(10): error C2355: 'this' : can only be referenced inside non-static member functions
1>test.cpp(10): error C2227: left of '->cbPort' must point to class/struct/union/generic type
1>test.cpp(10): error C2227: left of '->Items' must point to class/struct/union/generic type
1>test.cpp(10): error C2227: left of '->AddRange' must point to class/struct/union/generic type
```

And here is my form header file: http://pastebin.com/gGfMiwVr
It is basically only the generated code.

I feel like I am missing something extremely fundamental here, but my c++ skills aren't too great, yet.

When I place the searchPorts function as it is in the first example above into the form header file, it compiles no problem.

**EDIT:**

I have just solved my own problem! I had to declare the function within the DeltaForm class with the line:

```
private: void searchPorts(void);
```

Since the separate c++ file was not defining the functions within the class. Is it possible to split classes over multiple c++ files so I do not need to declare the function first? Alternatively, is it possible to reference the form objects from outside the class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problems are likely unrelated to the CLR.

In your first code, you show a free function. A free function does not belong to a class (it is not a member function of your DeltaForm) and thus has no access to the "this" pointer. It is not associated to an instance of a class, or to a class at all.

In your second code, you are probably closer to what you want, but you are most likely not declaring the searchPorts member function within the class.

You need to add a declaration to the class header:

```
class DetalForm
{
    /* ... */
    void DeltaForm::searchPorts(void);
    */ ... */
};
```

Do not forget the semicolon.

Declarations in the class header won't have a body. The body would actually be your (second) code snippet.

Comment: Thanks :D silly me I should know to declare it first. Is there a way to extend the class over multiple files? Simply declaring it in the header file is easy enough so I can't imagine I would want to try and extend a class over multiple files in this case. But I wouldn't mind knowing in the interest of learning.

Comment: @Chris: #Includes are handled at a preprocessor level so theoretically you could split the class declaration over as many files as you wanted by #including the different parts. I've never seen it done, though. Probably not a good idea.